# Compiler disagreement on using std::vector in constexpr context

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, constexpr

The following code compiles with gcc and MSVC, but not with clang.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

consteval void foo(auto func) {
    std::array<int, func().size()> f;
}

int main() {
    foo([](){ return std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4,5};});
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PadTK7cEE)

If I understand [the rules](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.17) of dynamic memory allocation in constant expressions correctly, this should be allowed because the memory is deallocated immediately. Is this a bug in clang? Or even undefined behaviour?

Comment: Does Clang implement `constexpr std::vector`? (I'm sure MSVC and libstdc++ are already implemented).

Comment: @康桓瑋 I think I does, I can construct a `std::vector` in a `consteval` function.

Comment: [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20) says you need clang 15.  Could be compiler explorer is behind on the libc++ version.

Comment: @NathanOliver  Ah, hm, this could be of course. Unfortunately I'm on my mac at the moment and clang15 is not yet installable so I can't test it.

Comment: What's curious is that the feature test macro of `__cpp_lib_constexpr_vector` does exist on clang 15 in compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/PKK3eG1nf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a bug in Clang. It seems to not consider the deallocations happening at the end of expressions as template arguments as part of the constant (full-)expression. When using a `constexpr` variable to store the size instead of a template argument, Clang accepts it as well.

A simplified test case (not depending on `std::vector` constexpr support):

```
struct V {
    int* v = new int[10];
    constexpr ~V() { delete[] v; }
    constexpr int size() { return 10; }
};

template<auto>
struct A {};

int main() {
    constexpr auto x = V{}.size(); //1
    using T = A<V{}.size()>;       //2
}
```

Clang accepts `//1`, but not `//2`.

On a quick look at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues I couldn't find a matching issue, so it might make sense to report it.

Comment: Yeah, I skimmed through the issues, too, but couldn't find onw either. I'll go ahead and open one. Thanks for investigating this.